# How to make sure preloader doesn't display on every page? PreloadJS

Tags: drupal-7, preloader, easeljs

I am preloading my website with preloadJS, but when going to an other page, I want to get rod of the preloader (because the whole website is already loaded), but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `localStorage` or a cookie and set a flag after the first preload and whenever the page is entered again you'd have to check if the flag is set and either hide the preloading-process or not.
To set the flag, instead of `localStorage` you could also use the jQuery cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

---

My **question** would be though: Why do you preload everything for a page that features page-changes? That would seem to me sort of against the purpose. - What exactly are you preloading?